# Get Int from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
    class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.100/index.php?kod=1eba7936&mode=1");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(code==200){
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                if (in != null) {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String line = "";

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                        result += line;
                }
                in.close();
            }

            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return result;

    }

   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      System.out.println(result);
  super.onPostExecute(result);

   }

}
```

I got such class, its work great exept i cannot catch variable as it returns void. The result its single integer value. And System.out.println(result) display proper value on console.

I call function from MainActivity with

```
new GetData().execute();
```

My goal is to have result from GetData as integer variable in MainActivity.

Comment: you can use static variable maybe? In the onPostExecute write to the static variable and read whenever you need

Comment: The result that you get in onPostExecute is the one you should use. It's already "in your MainActivity" if you start the task from there. The onPostExecute is called on the main thread. Just parse the variable to int and use it.

Comment: You could pass a callback method to the task and call it in `onPostExecute` with the value.

Comment: I know where is result, but i do not know how to get it. Still learning ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made new class with public string

```
public class Data {
    public static String data;
}
```

In onPostExecute i add:

```
Data.data = result.toString();
```

And now i can use Data.data as string whetever i want.